# How bright are the dimmest LEDs and what's their typical usage?

Tags: led, light, brightness

High power extremely bright LEDs are more and more popular in various lighting applications.

What about extremely dim low power LEDs? How bright are those and how are they typically used?

Comment: If you take an LED and don't power it, it is VERY dim.

Comment: Could the "unclear what you're asking" close-voter explain what is unclear please?

Comment: I am not the "unclear what you are asking" voter. But I find it also very unclear what you are asking. On what LEDs are you looking at in particular? do you mean low power LEDs (like < 10mA)? The Question "How bright are low power LEDs" can be answered from the datasheet. And the question "for what are they typically used" is too broad. You use them if you need low power and a visual indicator. If you are looking for the LED which consumes the lowest power or something else you may should reword your question.

Answer (score 3):

Any LED can be dimmed arbitrarily without changing its colour, unlike filament bulbs. This includes dimming it below the point where it can be seen with the naked eye. Maybe it would be more useful to look for the "smallest", e.g. this from [Kingbright](http://www.kingbright-europe.de/kingbright-develops-the-smallest-smd-led-package-2/) with sub-millimeter dimensions.

[It seems a special LED has been constructed which can emit individual photons](http://arstechnica.com/science/2012/04/doped-diamond-sends-single-photons-flying/). That probably counts as the "dimmest".

Comment: Ah! The NV-doped diamonds. I bet you were waiting to be able to link that. :-P Whether "without changing its colour" is technically fully true when you also include dimming below can be seen is of course something we could argue ages about. 1 or 2 nm shift is very easily achieved with thermal or current changes in many types ;-). Still, you get +1 though.

Comment: Found it while googling for this question :) It's a nifty device.

Answer (score 2):

Long before the development of high-brightness LEDs, they have been used as low-power and long-life indicator lights.

The brightness can be as little as nearly imperceptible in a dark room, but typically if you can't see it it's not useful, right?

In extremely low-power applications, they may flash periodically to convey information while only consuming microwatts.